# Why does't os module run wget cmd command?

Tags: python, python-requests, wget, python-os

I'm trying to download a zip file off the web and trying to download it by console command using wget -O fileName urlLink, but when trying the code, CMD opens for a second then closes and I canno't find the file anywhere.

I've tried using other ways of getting the file downloaded, but they return ERROR 403. Using wget in CMD downloads the right file, but not in the python code.

```py
def gotoDownload(link):
    try:
        with requests.Session().get(link) as download:
            if isUrlOnline(download):
                soup = BeautifulSoup(download.content, 'html.parser')
                filtered = soup.find_all('script')
                zip_file_url = re.search(r"('http.*?')", filtered[17].text).group().replace("'", "")

                os.system("wget -O {0} {1}".format('CreatureFinalZTL.zip', zip_file_url))
```

Expect the file to download
Instead doesn't download anything.

Comment: note that there is a python `wget` package...

Comment: you should drop os.system and use subprocess.run. Also pass arguments as list. In your case it's very possible that `zip_file_url` contains strange characters which make your command line fail

Comment: Such as the `&` character in URL query strings.

Comment: The string is: http://mediafile.cloud/b34b4f6720a31f73?pt=VEZGV1VrNVFXVEZPUWpsYVRHeFVhM0ZtYUdOUFFUMDlPdnJCa20rVzVvZnYrZ1kxQXdraGgvWT0%3D , It shouldn't create any complications. Regex returns the same result.

Comment: And the wget package returns 403 error.

Comment: Edit: The wget module doesn't do anything, it does not download any files and the script keeps continuing on.

Comment: Okay I tried launching the script in my CMD, it responds with wget is not recognized as an internal or external command, why is that? wget works in cmd as well as python?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that may help here (it may or may not solve your problem, because it is dependent on the your machine's setup and configuration). First, one thing I would suggest is to be more specific on the paths. You can use absolute paths in the wget line like so:

```
"wget -O {0} {1}".format('/path/to/output/dir/CreatureFinalZTL.zip', zip_file_url)
```

This is usually helpful in case the Python environment does not operate in a directory you are expecting. Alternatively, you can force the directory with the following python command:

```
os.chdir( path )
```

Then, you can operate with relative paths without worry. A second thing I would suggest is to confirm that the url is what you are expecting. Just print it out like so:

```
print( zip_file_url )
```

It might sound silly, but it is important to confirm that your regex is operating correctly.

Comment: I did try that, but sadly it did not work :(, regex is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `subprocess` instead.

```
import subprocess

...

subprocess.run(["wget",  "-O", 'CreatureFinalZTL.zip', zip_file_url])
```

This avoids any shell involvement with the command you wish to run.

Comment: I tried it, but it says FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specifie, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, had to re-add wget to PATHS on windows.